# Report Builder expression to remove line breaks if the field is empty

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm developing a Report based upon data submitted to a SQL Server via an online form. One section is a list of check boxes to indicate services required. I've written an expression in Report Builder to concatenated the fields into one column and, for easy reading in the repor, decided to add a carriage return + (VbCrLf).

=Fields!Service1.Value + (VbCrLf) + Service2.Value + (VbCrLf) + Service3.Value + (VbCrLf) + Service4.Value ETC. ETC.

Problem is every field results in a carriage return so there can be massive gaps if the 1st, 8th and 12th Services are chosen.

Is there a way to make the expression ignore the VbCrLf if the field is Null or Blank? Or any suggestions for a different or better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Design view, right-click the design surface outside the border of the report and click Report Properties.
2. Click Code.
3. In Custom code, type the code

.

```
Public Function ConcatFields(ByVal s As String) As String
   If String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then
      Return ""
   End If
   Return s + Environment.NewLine
End Function
```

Then invoke the function as follows:

```
=Code.ConcatFields(Fields!Service1.Value) + Code.ConcatFields(Service2.Value) + Code.ConcatFields(Service3.Value) + Code.ConcatFields(Service4.Value) ETC. ETC.
```

Comment: Hi Sergio. That didn't work either, throws up an error: The GroupExpression expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ contains an error: [BC30451] Name SERVICE2 not declared. (I'm just using SERVICE2 to avoid confusion, I'm using the proper field name in the expression).

Comment: You probably have to invoke Service2 as `Fields!Service2.Value`. Try out the function by concatenating only one field and see if that gives you an error...

Comment: Hi Sergio, I've been on leave for two weeks so couldn't get back to you. Your last suggestion worked PERFECTLY. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mt first reaction was to wrap the whole expression in a replace function, and replace 2 consecutive VbCrLf with a single one

```
=replace(Fields!Service1.Value + (VbCrLf) + Service2.Value + (VbCrLf) + 
Service3.Value + (VbCrLf) + Service4.Value,Vbcrlf+VbCrLf,VbCrLf)
```

The problem here is that you 3 empty values would still produce 2 new lines, so you could either nest the replace function so it applies 2 or 3 times, or you could do use an inline `IF` to test each value before adding a new line

```
=Fields!Service1.Value + iif(Service2.Value is nothing or Service2.Value = "","",VbCrLf)  + Service2.Value + iif(Service3.Value is nothing or Service3.Value = "","",VbCrLf) etc etc
```

Comment: You could probably shorten this using `...IIF(LEN(Fields!Service2.Value)=0,"", VbCrLf) ....`

Comment: Hi Jamie and Alan, tried the inline If but it didn't work. Amended it to:

Comment: Hi Jamie and Alan, tried the inline If but it didn't work at all. Amended it to: =IIF(Fields!SERVICE1.Value) Is Nothing, "", (Fields!SERVICE1.Value)  & VBCRLF &
IIF(Fields!SERVICE2.Value) Is Nothing, "", (Fields!SERVICE2.Value)  & VBCRLF) &
IIF(Fields!SERVICE3.Value) Is Nothing, "", (Fields!SERVICE3.Value)  & VBCRLF) &
IIF(Fields!SERVICE4.Value) Is Nothing, "", (Fields!SERVICE4.Value)  & VBCRLF etc. That did create the carriage returns but also the gaps. IO'll try again tomorrow.